# Setting differing ACLs on directories and files

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, file-permissions, acl

I want to set up default permissions for a file share so that everyone can `rwx` all of the directories and so that all newly created files are `rw`.

Everyone who is accessing this share is in the same group, so this isn't a concern.

I have looked at doing this via ACLs without changing all of the users' umasks and such. Here are my current invocations:

```
setfacl -Rdm g:mygroup:rwx share_name
setfacl -Rm g:mygroup:rwx share_name
```

My problem is that while I want all of the newly created *sub-directories* to be `rwx`, I only want newly created *files* to be `rw`.

Does anyone have a better method to achieve my desired end-result? Is there some way to set ACLs on directories separately from files, in a similar vein to `chmod +x` vs. `chmod +X`?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Gilles points out, `setfacl` default permissions specify the maximum permissions, basically replacing the `umask`.  So newly created files will be `rw` unless the application that created the file asked specially for it to be executable.

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/oldfile
$ getfacl test/oldfile
# file: test/oldfile
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

$ setfacl -m d:g:mygroup:rwx test
$ touch test/newfile
$ getfacl test/newfile
# file: test/newfile
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rw-
group::r-x                         #effective:r--
group:mygroup:rwx                  #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Note the effective perms above.  (There are only a few programs that will ask to set the execute bit on files that it creates, e.g. `gcc` for executables and `cp` if the file being copied was executable.)

Or did you mean that the first setfacl command was working the way you wanted, but the second one wasn't?  In other words, you're looking to fix up permissions on the old files, making sure that directories are traversable, without giving other regular files execute permissions?

My version of `setfacl` allows `X` exactly like you want, e.g.:

`setfacl g:mygroup:rwX`

```
$ setfacl --version
setfacl 2.2.49
$ rm -r test
$ mkdir test
$ mkdir test/olddir
$ touch test/oldfile
$ find test -ls
107513    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser    myuser        4096 Dec 22 01:56 test
107539    0 -rw-r--r--   1 myuser    myuser           0 Dec 22 01:56 test/oldfile
107529    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 myuser    myuser        4096 Dec 22 01:56 test/olddir
$ setfacl -Rm g:somegroup:rwx test
$ find test -ls
107513    4 drwxrwxr-x   3 myuser    myuser        4096 Dec 22 01:56 test
107539    0 -rw-rwxr--   1 myuser    myuser           0 Dec 22 01:56 test/oldfile
107529    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 myuser    myuser        4096 Dec 22 01:56 test/olddir
$ rm -r test
$ mkdir test
$ mkdir test/olddir
$ touch test/oldfile
$ setfacl -Rm g:somegroup:rwX test
$ find test -ls
107513    4 drwxrwxr-x   3 myuser    myuser        4096 Dec 22 01:56 test
107539    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 myuser    myuser           0 Dec 22 01:56 test/oldfile
107529    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 myuser    myuser        4096 Dec 22 01:56 test/olddir
```

If your version of `setfacl` doesn't support that, why not use `find`?

*overwrite permissions, setting them to rw for files and rwx for dirs*

```
$ find . \( -type f -exec setfacl -m g:mygroup:rw '{}' ';' \) \
      -o \( -type d -exec setfacl -m g:mygroup:rwx '{}' ';' \)
```

*set mygroup ACL permissions based on existing group permissions*

```
$ find . \( -perm -g+x -exec setfacl -m g:mygroup:rw '{}' ';' \) \
      -o \( -exec setfacl -m g:mygroup:rwx '{}' ';' \)
```

You'll probably want to check that the group mask provides effective permissions.  If not, you'll have to run this too:

```
$ find . -type d -exec chmod g+rwX '{}' ';'
```

Answer (score 9):

For future readers, to use `setfacl` on existing files/folders without adding the executable bit to your files, the solution is this part of [@Mikel's answer](https://superuser.com/a/224728/698422):

> My version of setfacl allows X exactly like you want, e.g.:
>
> `setfacl g:mygroup:rwX`

Relevant excerpt from the [`setfacl` documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html):

> The perms field is a combination of characters that indicate  the 
>   permissions: read (r), write (w), execute (x), **execute only if the
>   file is a directory or already  has  execute  permission  for  some 
>   user  (X)**.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand Linux ACLs, `setfacl -Rdm g:mygroup:rwx share_name` does exactly what you want. Experiment:

```
umask 007
mkdir foo
chgrp mygroup foo
chmod 2700 foo
setfacl -d -m group:mygroup:rwx foo
setfacl -m group:mygroup:rwx foo
touch foo/data
echo '#!/bin/ls' >foo/exec
chmod +x foo/exec
```

Then as a different user in group `mygroup`:

```
$ cat foo/*
#!/bin/ls
#!/bin/ls
$ ./foo/data
ash: ./foo/data: Permission denied
$ ./foo/exec
./foo/exec
```

What's going on?

```
$ getfacl foo/data
# file: foo/data
# owner: myuser
# group: mygroup
user::rw-
group::---
group:mygroup:rwx                 #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

The effective ACL for `mygroup` is the result of and'ing the `ACL_GROUP` entry for `mygroup` (`rwx`) with the ACL_MASK entry (`rw-`).

The [acl(5) man page](http://acl.bestbits.at/man/man5/acl.txt) explains calculation this under “Access check algorithms”. It doesn't explain how `ACL_MASK` entries are generated, but in practice the right thing seems to happen.